# MySQL UNION does not work consistently. If I switch the posision of two clause, the results are different each other

Tags: mysql

According to the position of clauses, mysql results differently.

```
SELECT sum(if(bos = 'B', txn_qty*-1, txn_qty)) as qty 
FROM tstock_txn 
WHERE date_format(txn_date, '%Y%m') >= '201905' and company_id='003490' 
union all
SELECT qty as qty FROM tstock_txn_temp WHERE company_id='003490'
```

result: correct

```
-290
290
```

changed query

```
SELECT qty as qty 
FROM tstock_txn_temp 
WHERE company_id='003490' 
union ALL 
SELECT sum(if(bos = 'B', txn_qty*-1, txn_qty)) as qty
FROM tstock_txn 
WHERE date_format(txn_date, '%Y%m') >= '201905' and company_id='003490'
```

result: not correct

```
290
0
```

the result should be

```
290
-290
```

Comment: try to output data without sum and without if. Something like this: `SELECT qty as qty, 1, 2 
FROM tstock_txn_temp 
WHERE company_id='003490' 
union ALL 
SELECT bos, txn_qty*-1, txn_qty
FROM tstock_txn 
WHERE date_format(txn_date, '%Y%m') >= '201905' and company_id='003490' `. Also try to add `group by`.

Comment: I wouldn't expect a difference can you publish sample data that proves your assertion?

Comment: without sum or with group by returns the same wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce your issue.

```
drop table if exists tstock_txn,tstock_txn_temp;
create table tstock_txn_temp
(company_id int,qty int);
insert into tstock_txn_temp values (003490,200);

create table tstock_txn
(company_id int, txn_date date,bos varchar(1), txn_qty int);

insert into tstock_txn values
(003490,'2019-05-01','b',100),
(003490,'2019-05-01','b',100);

SELECT sum(if(bos = 'B', txn_qty*-1, txn_qty)) as qty 
FROM tstock_txn 
WHERE date_format(txn_date, '%Y%m') >= '201905' and company_id='003490' 
union all
SELECT qty as qty FROM tstock_txn_temp WHERE company_id=003490;

+------+
| qty  |
+------+
| -200 |
|  200 |
+------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)

SELECT qty as qty FROM tstock_txn_temp WHERE company_id='003490' 
union ALL 
SELECT sum(if(bos = 'B', txn_qty*-1, txn_qty)) as qty
FROM tstock_txn 
WHERE date_format(txn_date, '%Y%m') >= '201905' and company_id='003490' ;

+------+
| qty  |
+------+
|  200 |
| -200 |
+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Yes, that's why I posted my question. The results of phpMyAdmin and SQL in PHP are the same. Both are wrong. I folllowed your script in shell, the result is correct as you. I'll try reproduce this case in shell.

Answer (score 0):

Now I found the reason of the problem.
The attribute of qty column of tstock_txn_temp is unsigned int.
So the below clause's value is changed to zero.

My dev table attribues and product table atributes are a little diffetent.
So I counldn't find the root cause in the shell.

Anyway I think this is kind of ridiculous.

You can reproduce as follow:
alter table tstock_txn_temp change qty qty int unsigned ;

Thank you everybody.